# trying to create in oracle a table named phone

Tags: oracle11g

I am trying to create in oracle a table named phone. the phone is identified by its number which it must contain 12 digits and it must start with: 35566,35567,35568,35569. it must contain also an activation date and a flag which show if it is activated or not..can anybody help me with an example sript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the resulting table will be something like that

`create table phones(
 phone_number varchar2(12),
 activated number(1) default 0,
 activation_date date default null,
 CONSTRAINT phone_number_check
  CHECK (substr(phone_number,1,5) in( '35566','35567','35568','35569') ),
 CONSTRAINT activated_check
  CHECK (activated in(1,0) ) 
)`

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer,it was very helpful.beside this table i also created a table named clients,it holds data about the clients who own the phones,their id and their name.now i need to create another table named phone call which needs to store data about when the call started,when it endeed and the clients that took part.i need the script of the third table

Comment: CREATE TABLE dj_abonent 
( 
dj_klientID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
emer_klienti varchar2(10), 
mbiemer_klienti VARCHAR2(10),
sasia_cel INT
);

CREATE TABLE dj_phones
(
 phone_number varchar2(12),
 activated number(1) default 0,
 activation_date date default null,
 CONSTRAINT dj_phone_number_check
CHECK (substr(phone_number,1,5) in( '35566','35567','35568','35569') ),
 CONSTRAINT dj_activated_check
  CHECK (activated in(1,0) ) 
);

Comment: this is the script so far

Comment: in oracle you have to use number instead of int, also to define primary key you will need to use this kind of statement `CONSTRAINT constraint_name PRIMARY KEY (column1, column2, ... column_n)`

Comment: than you..I am trying now to create a new table phonecall but I dont know how to store the time when te call started and ended and the clients that took part (the clients are stored in the client table) I tried this script.. CREATE TABLE phonecall
(
start_ time TIME,
end_time TIME, first_client VARCHAR2(10), second_client VARCHAR2(10));

Comment: use `date` type, `date ` type also contains time, to get time from `date` you will use `to_date/to_char` functions pointing the format you need

Comment: can you send me an example script please i also need to store data about the clients that took part in the conversation  ,i really have issues with this table because i am not very familiar with oracle.